# Symfony dom crawler with css selector is not finding all matches

Tags: css, symfony

Given the following html

[image: amzimg]
Full html can be found here: http://pastebin.com/B3JASXwx

and using the Dom Crawler code

```
$pd->filter('.content > ul > li')->each(function(Crawler $node, $i){})
```

when looping over the results, it's stopping at the first `<script>` tag nested under the `<ul>` element, and instead only returning 9 elements, instead of all 14 `<li>` elements.

Is this a bug, or by design, and is there any for me to get all `<li>` items without resorting to a preg_match?

Comment: I cannot reproduce your issue. I wrote a little example (see https://gist.github.com/xabbuh/ad04b9dad5424b8c6af4260d1da15af0) which results in `13` as expected. You may need to provide more imformation regarding your problem.

Comment: that's a snippet of an amazon product page, so I'm wondering if the full page html is malformed and it's screwing up the Crawler somehow.
I'll edit the original post to include a pastebin of the full html that I'm working with. Full html block added to question.

Comment: Yeah, I can reproduce that with your example code. I tend to think that this is related to some malformed code from the Amazon web site but I didn't investigate further.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've implemented stripping out all .* tags before feeding the HTML to the Symfony DOM parser, that seems to have cured the issue I was having.

Given the  tags themselves contained DOM modifying code, I'm guessing that the Symfony parser was incorrectly reading the DOM tags inside the  tags as valid tags, and not javascript modifications.

TL;DR - before passing your raw html into Symfony, make sure you strip out all  tags